# Wanted coordinate grid

Tags: coordinates

I am currently using the latest qgis and arcgis software and would like to know if someone can provide me the steps on how to create the following:

1.A blank drawing showing coordinate grid 500’x500’ for all of zone 2 harn nad 83.

2.Format files need to be able to work with civil 3d 2016

Answer (score 3):

Creating a grid is a trivial task in either QGIS or ArcGIS. The process is explained in detail the software manuals and many tutorials easily found through a quick internet search, so it would be redundant to repeat them here.

Exporting to a file format "able to work with civil 3d 2016" is a separate question. The technical documentation for "civil 3d 2016" should contain a list of compatible formats (we'll call this list 1).

Then go to the technical documentation for the two GIS softwares you have, and find a list of what formats they can output in (we'll call these list 2 and list 3). Cross-reference list 1 with lists 2 and 3 to figure out if either program can produce any of the compatible formats. If not, you need to find a software tool that can convert from any format on list 2 or 3, to any format on list 1.